# Returning an output value via C# WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm looking to return a string value to the client via my HTTP post service on WCF.

I can return a status code okay via the following:

> WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode
>   = HttpStatusCode.OK;

... however I'm not entirely sure how to return a string value to the client.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Nick

```
namespace TextWCF
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IShortMessageService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "invoke", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [OperationContract]
    void PostSMS(Stream input);

}
}

[OperationBehavior]
    public void PostSMS(Stream input)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Dispose();
        NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);

        string user = Convert.ToString(qs["user"]);
        string password = qs["password"];
        string api_id = qs["api_id"];
        string to = qs["to"];
        string text = qs["text"];
        string from = qs["from"];

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse. = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
```

Comment: Your methods are set a `void`s. You can change the declaration of your method e.g. `public string PostSMS(Stream input)` if you wanted to return a `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your method actually return something as Neil pointed out.

So just change your method signature to look like

```
namespace TextWCF
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IShortMessageService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "invoke", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [OperationContract]
    string PostSMS(Stream input);

}
}

[OperationBehavior]
    public string PostSMS(Stream input)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Dispose();
        NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);

        string user = Convert.ToString(qs["user"]);
        string password = qs["password"];
        string api_id = qs["api_id"];
        string to = qs["to"];
        string text = qs["text"];
        string from = qs["from"];

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse. = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return "Some String";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I'm trying to send a blank page over HTTP with the string contained within it.  Would that work for this purpose? Thanks